# How to use pallet Instance in Xcm?

Tags: polkadot, xcm, substrate-parachain-template, xcmv3

I was using xcm and while filling parameters in `destination`, I encountered through a field `Interior:xcmv2multilocationJunction`
and i selected `x1` there . After that there is `x1:xcmv2Junction` which contains different options.

My query is how to use `PalletInstance` there. Could anyone guide me through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PalletInstance` is just an `u8` representing the index of a pallet within the relevant runtime. For example, in [Polkadot Asset Hub](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-assets), `"PalletInstance":50` refers to the assets pallet. Hence the junction is pointing to a location which is within the asset pallet storage, i.e., a specific asset living in the asset pallet of the Polkadot Asset Hub.

[Here you have more information](https://github.com/paritytech/xcm-format#interior-locations--junctions) of all the possible junction types and other relevant information about multi locations in XCM.